# I want to sort my products list in a descending order

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, pagination

I want to sort my product page in a descending order that is I want recently added products to show first when you open the product page. While I was trying to paginate the product page, It works fine but the problem is old products are shown first.

Here is my part of my  code

```
 $per_page = 15;
 if(isset($_GET["page"]) && is_numeric($_GET['page'])){
  $page = $_GET["page"]; 
  }else{
    $page = 1;
    }
  $start_from = ($page-1) * $per_page;

  $query = "SELECT * FROM products LIMIT $start_from, $per_page DESC ";
  $post = $db->select($query);
    if($post){
        while($result = $post->fetch_assoc()){
```

When I add DESC at the end of the query it shows an error saying "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DESC' at line 130" but when I remove it works fine but it does not sort in a descending order. Old products come first instead of being at the end of the page.

Comment: The correct syntax is `"SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY column DESC LIMIT $start_from, $per_page"`

Comment: You need to use ORDER BY field DESC.

Comment: What do the field signify? It still creates an error Unknown column 'field' in 'order clause'30

Comment: Do you have an auto increment column? or a date column? that is the field.

Comment: field signify either auto_increment column or date inserted column in products table.

Comment: Ohh i see in my products table the autoincremment column is the productId column. So I should write  
"SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY productId DESC LIMIT $start_from, $per_page "

Comment: Thank you guys, It is now working. I love this online forum, it always helps

Answer (score 3):

The syntax you want for your query is

```
"SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY fieldtoorderby DESC LIMIT $start_from, $per_page"
```

Comment: What does  ORDER BY FieldToOrderBy DESC signifies it still creates an error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY FieldToOrderBy DESC' at line 130

Comment: Thank you guys, It is now working. I love this online forum, it always helps